# Unity. В чём ошибка в коде?

Tags: unity3d

Программа для выбрасывания предметов из инвентаря.
Красным подсвечивается transform и код выдаёт следующею ошибку:

> Assets\Scripts\inventory\Spawn.cs(11,62): error CS1061: 'GameObject[]'
> does not contain a definition for 'transform' and no accessible
> extension method 'transform' accepting a first argument of type
> 'GameObject[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
> assembly reference?)

Сам код

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Spawn : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject item;
    private Transform player;
    private void Start()
    {
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player").transform;
    }
    public void SpawnDroppedItem()
    {
        Vector2 playerPos = new Vector2(player.position.x + 2, player.position.y - 1);
        Instantiate(item, playerPos, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
player = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player")[0].transform;
```

ибо `FindGameObjectsWithTag` - массив